# How do I make a string array based on a text file with newline delimited entries in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, text-files, delimited

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# how to convert File.ReadLines into string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220993/c-sharp-how-to-convert-file-readlines-into-string-array)

I have a text file that I want to make a String array from. The file is newline delimited. For example,

entry1

entry2

entry3

will make an array of {"entry1", "entry2", "entry3"}

EDIT: I am wanting to do this using DownloadString in WebClient

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220993/c-sharp-how-to-convert-file-readlines-into-string-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271225/c-sharp-reading-a-file-line-by-line Google things first before asking or check SO questions

Comment: Problem is that I doing this using the DownloadString method in WebClient and I want to avoid downloading it to a temp dir.

Answer (score 3):

So you're just trying to split a string into an array that is delimited with a new line?

If so, this should work:

```
string temp = webClient.DownloadString(someurl);
string[] lines = temp.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Good luck.