# Reading valid email address from text files

Tags: c#, .net

I have a plain text file. The requirement is to read valid email addresses from text file.

The text file does not contain any special characters and contains one word per line.

**Sample**

```
test1
test@yahoo.com
test2
test@gmail.com
```

I have tried to read the text file as follows,

```
var emails = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt");
```

But unable to find how to extract valid emails from text file.

I'm using C# 4.0

Comment: For C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/c-sharp-regex-email-validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If only your e-mail lines has `@` character, you can use

```
var emails = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt").Where(line => line.Contains("@"));
```

Ok, I admit it. This is the worst e-mail validation I have ever seen `:)` Let's go more deep. You can check your line with using [`MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) class. Let's define a method for checking e-mail address is valid or not like;

```
public bool IsValidMailAddress(string s)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then we can use;

```
var emails = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt").Where(line => IsValidMailAddress(line));
```

Comment: @aiapatag That's why I said `only your e-mail lines has @`

Comment: You also missed a parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Too overkill for my taste. I wouldn't add a reference to a namespace just to get one function from it, irregardless of what my app really does. I would suggest to use System.Net.Mail namespace ONLY if you need to send e-mail using SMTP. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1fb84h.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to do this. Look into this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx) as your reference.

Excerpt from MSDN:

```
   public bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
   {
       invalid = false;
       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strIn))
          return false;

       // Use IdnMapping class to convert Unicode domain names. 
       try {
          strIn = Regex.Replace(strIn, @"(@)(.+)$", this.DomainMapper,
                                RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
       }
       catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException) {
         return false;
       }

       if (invalid) 
          return false;

       // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format. 
       try {
          return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, 
                @"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" + 
                @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,17}))$", 
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
       }  
       catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException) {
          return false;
       }
   }
```

Then use it by:

```
 var emails = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt");
 foreach(var line in emails)
 {
     if(IsValidEmail(line))
     { //do something with the valid email
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi use regular expression to filter the valid email addresses.

sample code is given below.

```
var emails = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt")
                       .Where(x => x.IsValidEmailAddress());

public static class extensionMethods
    {
        public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string s)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$");
            return regex.IsMatch(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are doing right. you are calling `ReadAllLines` method, that returns the `array` already. Only you need to do a foreach loop. as:

```
var emails = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt");
foreach (var email in emails)
{
    //write validation logic of emails here
}
```

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220993/c-sharp-how-to-convert-file-readlines-into-string-array) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by valid. Some people take a simple approach and just look for an '@' and at least one '.' in the string. Others take email validation much further and attempt to validate addresses against [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)

It looks as if the simply approach would work for your needs.